# Erlang deps loading

Tags: erlang, project-structure

I'm trying to write erlang first app. It has
https://github.com/emedia-project/erlffmpeg in deps, I have almost the
same Makefile.

When I run erlang shell in erlffmpeg dir and eval README
example, all ok. But When I do it from my project's dir, I get error
like: `ucp detect undef`. So, my erl shell see the fns from ffmpeg
module, but when i try to eval this fns it seems like shell doesn't know
about inheritant deps of ffmpeg.

I run erl shell with `make dev` command. In short, it does `erl -pa ebin
deps/*/ebin`

Seems like i'm missing some knowledge about module loading.
What should I do with this and what you advice me to read?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So, the answer is to use `rebar` and set the deps like:

```
{deps, [
   {ffmpeg, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/emedia-project/erlffmpeg", "master"}}
]}.
```

In this case `rebar` will automatically download all iner dependencies in root `deps` folder, so the shell with command `erl -pa ebin deps/*/ebin` will hook up all `.beam` files.

Big thanks to friendly #erlang members.

Comment: You can also run `rebar shell` to get an erl repl with the load path set up correctly for your application and its dependencies.